# Filtering a stream

Tags: filter, stream, java-stream, compare, filtering

I've been trying to filter this list of Employees based on employee surnames.

I'm trying to move all the employees with the surname "Phillips to the back of the list"

```
emp = emp.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getSurname().contains("Phillips")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("List with Phillips at the back: " + emp);
```

Comment: you need to use filter rather sorted.

Comment: Unless you really have employees with the strange name “Phillips to the back of the list”, your quotes are misplaced. If, however, you actually mean employees named “Phillips” and want to move them to the back of the list, I don’t get your question. Changing the order, is not filtering but sorting and the code you’ve posted does the job (I’d use `equals` instead of `contains` though). So what’s your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need the mechanism as below,

```
public class Employee {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> employees = List.of(new Employee("John", "Mann"), new Employee("Steve", "Phillips"));

        List<Employee> collect = employees.stream()
                                           .filter(emp -> emp.getLastName()
                                                             .contains("Phillips"))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(collect);

    }
```

[Employee{firstName='Steve', lastName='Phillips'}]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

First you can create a `Comparator` class that check surname when comparing.

```
public class PhillipsComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        if (o1.getSurname().equalsIgnoreCase("Phillips") && !o2.getSurname().equalsIgnoreCase("Phillips")) {
            return 1;
        } else if (!o1.getSurname().equalsIgnoreCase("Phillips") && !o2.getSurname().equalsIgnoreCase("Phillips")) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have used `equalsIgnoreCase` method rather than `contain`.

Then create a new instance of your comparator.

```
PhillipsComparator phillipsComparator = new PhillipsComparator();
```

Use that to sort your employee list

```
employeeList.sort(phillipsComparator);
```